# Having more than 50 column in a SQL table

Tags: oracle, database-design

I have designed my database in such a way that One of my table contains 52 columns. All the attributes are tightly associated with the primary key attribute, So there is no scope of further Normalization.

Please let me know if same kind of situation arises and you don't want to keep so many columns in a single table, what is the other option to do that.

Comment: this is not a good design , afaik , e.g. think of insert query , you will have to put 50 values , and this obviously is not a good experience

Comment: if they are attributes of the primary key, it is really OK. I have tables with more than 250 columns. Can be perfectly normal.

Comment: 50+ columns is OK.  If they're attributes of the entity the table describes and it's in 3rd normal form then, OK, go with it.  If there are repeating fields or other violations of normalization rules there's more work to be done.

Comment: What is the rationale for not wanting to keep so many columns in a single table?

Comment: That's not very many columns. I just checked our Oracle EBS and I found several tables with more than 900 columns and one with 996 columns. I say if this properly models the data then don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table with fifty-two columns is not necessarily wrong.  As others have pointed out many databases have such beasts.  However I would not consider ERP systems as exemplars of good data design: in my experience they tend to be rather the opposite.

Anyway, moving on!

You say this:

> "All the attributes are tightly associated with the primary key
>   attribute"

Which means that your table is in third normal form (or perhaps BCNF).  That being the case it's not true that no further normalisation is possible.  Perhaps you can go to fifth normal form?

Fifth normal form is about removing join dependencies.  All your columns are dependent on the primary key but there may also be dependencies between columns: e.g, there are multiple values of COL42 associated with each value of COL23.  Join dependencies means that when we add a new value of COL23 we end up inserting several records, one for each value of COL42.  The [Wikipedia article on 5NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_normal_form) has a good worked example.

I admit not many people go as far as 5NF.  And it might well be that even with fifty-two columns you table is already in 5NF.  But it's worth checking.  Because if you can break out one or two subsidiary tables you'll have improved your data model and made your main table easier to work with.

Answer (score 3):

It is not odd in any way to have 50 columns. ERP systems often have 100+ columns in some tables.

One thing you could look into is to ensure most columns got valid default values (null, today etc). That will simplify inserts.

Also ensure your code always specifies the columns (i.e no "select *"). Any kind of future optimization will include indexes with a subset of the columns.

Answer (score 2):

One approach we used once, is that you split your table into two tables. Both of these tables get the primary key of the original table. In the first table, you put your most frequently used columns and in the second table you put the lesser used columns. Generally the first one should be smaller. You now can speed up things in the first table with various indices. In our design, we even had the first table running on memory engine (RAM), since we only had reading queries. If you need to get the combination of columns from table1 and table2 you need to join both tables with the primary key.

Comment: Interesting approach, not suitable for everyone but worth noting.

Answer (score -1):

Another option is the "item-result pair" (IRP) design over the "multi-column table" MCT design, especially if you'll be adding more columns from time to time.

```
MCT_TABLE
---------
KEY_col(s)
Col1
Col2
Col3
...


IRP_TABLE
---------
KEY_col(s)
ITEM
VALUE


select * from IRP_TABLE;


KEY_COL ITEM VALUE
------- ---- -----
1       NAME Joe
1       AGE  44
1       WGT  202
...
```

IRP is a bit harder to use, but much more flexible.

I've built very large systems using the IRP design and it can perform well even for massive data.  In fact it kind of behaves like a column organized DB as you only pull in the rows you need (i.e. less I/O) rather that an entire wide row when you only need a few columns (i.e. more I/O).